# Random walks intuition

Tags: probability-theory, random-walk

I came across the reflection principle and this explanation at [Is there an intuitive way to see this property of random walks?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222505/is-there-an-intuitive-way-to-see-this-property-of-random-walks)

However, I can't understand the reasoning in the answer about mirroring around point s where s is less than r and how it leads to the identity. Any help on understanding this would be appreciated.

Comment: Any reason this is being downvoted?

Comment: I don't see a reason. I upvoted. I think this is an exemplary question, pointing out specifically what you don't understand about an answer. Much preferable to the (more frequently practiced) alternatives of filling the comment space with new questions or asking the question all over again without saying which part of the answer you don't understand. (Note that it's only one down vote currently.)

Comment: @joriki Since then, the OP posted a comment to the answer they have trouble understanding, to which the author of the answer answered. This seems much preferable than opening some new question--especially when, as here, one omits to mention the new post on the old page (a most impolite practice, if you ask me).

Comment: @Did: On that last point, I wholeheartedly agree -- I only saw that the OP linked to the old post in the new one, which people often don't do -- I agree that linking to the new post in the old one is similarly important. About the first point, it depends on how complicated the follow-up question is. It can also be annoying when people keep asking follow-up questions in the comments that are really new questions. If it was cleared up by a single exchange in this case, I agree it didn't warrant a whole new question.